# hudson.FilePath is missing error when generate allure report via pipeline script

Tags: python, jenkins, allure

I added new stage to pipeline:

```
stage('reports') {
    steps {
    script {
            allure([
                    includeProperties: false,
                    jdk: '',
                    properties: [],
                    reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
                    results: [[path: 'target/allure-results']]
            ])
        }
    }
}
```

But job failed with error:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MissingContextVariableException: Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.StepDescriptor.checkContextAvailability(StepDescriptor.java:260)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:262)
Caused: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MissingContextVariableException: Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing
```

Tests are written on Python and xml report generated, but not allure report.

Can you please help me out in resolving the error ?

Comment: Do you have a `node() {}` around your `stage()`? This usually happens, when Jenkins doesn't have a node context - meaning the pipeline doesnt know on which node to execute the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, you use [declarative pipeline syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline). In that case, you need to define `agent` section. From official documentation:

> Defining `agent none` at the top-level of the Pipeline ensures that an Executor will not be assigned unnecessarily. Using `agent none` also forces each `stage` section to contain its own `agent` section.

So, I think that you're using `agent none` at the top-level of your pipeline, that's why you need to add `agent` section inside your stage. Something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent none 
    stages {
        stage('reports') {
            agent { docker 'openjdk:8-jre' }
            steps {
                script {
                    allure([
                        includeProperties: false,
                        jdk: '',
                        properties: [],
                        reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
                        results: [[path: 'target/allure-results']]
                    ])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For [scripted pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline) you need to use this syntax (see allure [documentation](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_jenkins) for more details):

```
node {
// script body

allure([
         includeProperties: false,
         jdk: '',
         properties: [[key: 'allure.issues.tracker.pattern', value: 'http://tracker.company.com/%s']],
         reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
         results: [[path: 'target/allure-results'], [path: 'other_target/allure-results']]
         ])
}
```